# Validation Error messages with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

After a few hours now of trying various validations for my nested-attributes (images), i have this validation that checks for a minimum of 1 image to be uploaded.

```
class AnimalImage < ActiveRecord::Base
mount_uploader :image, AnimalImageUploader
belongs_to :animal

validate :limit_num_of_images

def limit_num_of_images
  if image.size < 1
    errors[:base] << "Please add an image"
  end
end

end
```

Just to clarify something here, whenever a validation takes place im assuming it checks the parent model and then the child in that order if using nested_attributes ? you dont have to tell it to check to see if child validations are present?

My main question was the construction of the error message, it seems that setting errors[:base] generates an error message like so

```
Animal images base Please add an image
```

How do i set this up so that the user only sees the following as their error message

```
Please add an image
```

Thanks

Edit

This is how i am showing the messages in my view

```
<% @animal.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
```

Though as a quick fix i have created a helper to strip the unwanted text from the message (dont like it though as too hacky)

```
def error_edit(message)
  msg = message
  msg.gsub('Animal images base', ' ')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add)

```
errors.add(:base, "Message")
```

In your example:

```
class AnimalImage < ActiveRecord::Base
mount_uploader :image, AnimalImageUploader
belongs_to :animal

validate :limit_num_of_images

def limit_num_of_images
  if image.size < 1
    errors.add(:base, "Please add an image")
  end
end

end
```

Comment: that doesnt work either im afraid still get "Animal images base Please add an image" as the error message

Comment: How you are retrieving these messages?

Comment: ive updated the question with my view and a quick fix i have implemented

Comment: The issue seems to be still there with rails 5.2